# Android logcat command

Tags: android, android-logcat

I want to get "last 25 logs of tag name CordovaLog" 
I tried

```
logcat -t 25 CordovaLog
```

I do get 25 logs but of all the tag names. Also what if there are no 25 Cordova Log ? Will it return whatever is available.

So what is the right command ?
Thanks.

EDIT 1-

```
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -t 25 CordovaLog:V *:S"); 
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder(); 
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)  
        { 
                log.append(line+"<br />");
        } 
        return log.toString();
```

So Is this code getting all the logs are filting to get "Cordova logs" ? OR it's just getting "Cordova logs" ? 
It's crashing as I have lots of logs.

Comment: Can you post the output of the logcat for the crash? USing the code I give you below, you will get 25 or less lines of CordovaLog (only CordovaLog). The crash you are having could be for other reasons. I would suggest to close this question (and mark valid answer) and open another question if the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will open the different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct use will be

```
logcat -d -t 25 CordovaLog:V *:S
```

With this, you will print all that have the tag CordovaLog, and will silent everything else.
You can have more information in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Edite to fix the correct answer (see comment below). It will print the last 25 entries, or less in case there are less than 25 entries.

Comment: Don't you need the -s flag to filter logcat?

Comment: I believe that gives you CordovaLog output from the last 25 lines of logcat output. If you want the last 25 CordovaLog entries I would use "adb logcat -d CordovaLog:V *:S | tail -n 25"

Comment: Don't need the -s flag for filter. Just updated the answer. The filter (CordovaLog:V *:S) needs to be AFTER the options (-d -t 25) With this correct answer will print 25 or less entries (in case there are less entries)